# Query for 'Lead' object is not returning a Converted Account ID

Tags: leads, sobject

I am using the following JSforce command to get a specific lead:

jsobject('Lead').find({ Phone:number})...

The problem that I am running into is that I am getting data returned, but it seems to be missing the ConvertedAccountId, please see image below.

[image: ConvertedAccountId:null]

The key IsConverted = true at the bottom of the image, and IsDeleted = false, but ConvertedAccountId = null.

Is there a reason why ConvertedAccountId is not returning with the proper value?

Here is an additional image to show that the account itself has not been deleted.

[image: Account]

Comment: Could it be possible that the account or the contact has been deleted?

Comment: If you look at the bottom of the image, IsDeleted is false.  The account does show up in the Accounts tab.

Comment: The field IsDeleted concerns the lead object, not the Account object.

Comment: @YukiTokuda Have you tried querying the same in developer console or workbench to narrow down issue to JSforce library .

Comment: @MartinLezer - I have added an image to display that the account itself has not been deleted.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - I have not tested that yet.  This did work at one point.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to the Account record it was converted to, the account has been deleted since conversion. Deleting a record has the effect of placing a null in every lookup field that used to reference that record. Since there's no way to actually manipulate this field directly, that's the only possible explanation.

Comment: If you take a look at the second image that I posted, it will display the data specific to the account.  The IsDeleted key has a value of false.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right Account from the converted lead?

Comment: @YukiTokuda Correct. The *lead* has not been deleted. That field has nothing to do with the opportunity, contact, or account associated to the lead.

Comment: @sfdcfox To clarify, the first image is using the query: sobject('Lead').find({Phone: searchNumber})... 

And the second is: 
 sobject('Account').find({Phone: searchNumber})...

Comment: @YukiTokuda Phone numbers are not unique in the system. I'd guess that someone saw one of the accounts as a duplicate and deleted it instead of merging it with the existing account. Try checking your Recycle Bin; if this was a recent delete, it may still be there.

Comment: @sfdcfox There are "No records to display." in 'All Recycle Bin'.  I appreciate your help by the way.

Comment: As per the image, lhe lead is converted on 2015-08-07, whereas the account created date is 2015-08-12. Shouldn't both the dates be same, if it was the correct account?